# Css float. Как прижать ссылку справа?

Tags: float, css

В общем, если делаю так, то ссылка вылазит за пределы бэкграунда. :(

**css**

```
.company{
margin-left:50px;  
width:580px;  
/*border-bottom:#9EADA6 solid 1px;*/  
padding-bottom:10px;  
padding-left:10px;  
padding-top:10px;  
margin-bottom:10px;  
}  
.company h3, .company img{float:left;}  
.company img{ margin-right:10px;}  
.company h3{ font-size:26px; padding-right:20px;color:blue;}  
.company span{display:block; padding-top:3px;color:orange;}   
.company ul li{font-size:16px;}  
.company ul{padding-top:10px;}  
ul.one{width:240px;display:block;float:left;}  
ul.two{width:240px;display:block;float:left;}  
.clearleft{clear:left;}  
.company a {float:right;}  
.vip{background:#FEFEDA;}
```

**html**

```
<div class="company vip">
            <img src="http://bowl.hu/images/teams/dallas_cowboys_medium.png" width="80px" height="80px" />
            <h3>Компания</h3><span>(Город, район, улицатракт дом)</span>
            <ul class="one">
            <li>Услуга 1</li>
            <li>услуга 2</li>
            <li>услуга 3</li>
            </ul>    <ul class="two">
            <li>услуга 4</li>
            <li>Услуга 5</li>
            <li>Услуга 6</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearleft"></div>
            <a href="company/metallgrad/price.excel"><img src="http://www.itlearning.ro/forum/images/os/excel_2010_old.jpg" /></a><a href="company/metallgrad/price.excel">Скачать прайс</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: необходимо было использовать clearfix http://jsfiddle.net/La1qau8d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На .company добавьте float:left тоже. Тогда все будет ок.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Голос не смог добавить, недостаточно репутации :(